# Should Symfony DomCrawler/Goutte be this slow?

Tags: php, symfony, goutte

I'm using Symfony's Goutte library, which combines Guzzle, Symfony DomCrawler and CssSelector into one package, to scrape a fairly simple HTML table. However, I'm finding it incredibly slow.

It usually takes around 12-14 seconds to process a 20 row table once the page has been loaded. Surely this is far too long?

I've used DOM parsing libraries before and never encountered slowness like this. Am I doing something wrong, or is Goutte just very slow?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Goutte and DomCrawler component really are that slow. I tried phpQuery instead and am seeing the same work done in a fraction of a second. –

Comment: I have noticed tha same thing. Have you tried simple html dom parser?